# Sort bars of Stacked Bar Chart

Tags: vega-lite

For a Stacked Bar Chart, can you sort the bars by the size of one of the segments?

E.g., take this Stacked Bar Chart from the examples ([Open Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/examples/vega-lite/stacked_bar_h)):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {"url": "data/barley.json"},
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"aggregate": "sum", "field": "yield"},
    "y": {"field": "variety"},
    "color": {"field": "site"}
  }
}
```

[image: barley yield per site]

Now I would like to sort the y-axis based on the yield in *Crookston*. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting by the *total* of another field is relatively easy; you can do so with the `"sort"` entry of the desired encoding ([sort docs](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/sort.html#sort-by-encoding)):

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {"url": "data/barley.json"},
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"aggregate": "sum", "field": "yield"},
    "y": {"field": "variety", "sort": {"op": "sum", "field": "yield"}},
    "color": {"field": "site"}
  }
}
```

[image]

If you want to sort just by the value when `site == "Crookston"`, you can do so by first applying a [calculate transform](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/calculate.html) to select just that value:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {"url": "data/barley.json"},
  "transform": [
    {
      "calculate": "datum.site == 'Crookston' ? datum.yield : 0",
      "as": "crookston"
    }
  ],
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"aggregate": "sum", "field": "yield"},
    "y": {"field": "variety", "sort": {"op": "sum", "field": "crookston"}},
    "color": {"field": "site"}
  }
}
```

[image]